# Convert angular modules

Tags: javascript, angularjs, es6-modules

So I built a data persistence framework as an Angular 1 module (which you can find [here](https://github.com/andyhasit/SneakerJS)) and now want to use it in (or rewrite it for) other, non-angular apps, e.g. in React.

There is nothing in there that relates to UI functionality, routes, or anything else specific to angular (no controllers) it's just JavaScript objects which happen to be organised using angular's module system.

(Well nearly: it uses **$q** for promises, and integrates with the digest loop, but I'll be removing that bit and switching to another promise library to make it work outside of angular)

So what I want to do is rewrite this as a "JavaScript module" of sorts, but I don't know my way around those.

So my questions are:

- What format of modules should I be creating (AMD, CommonJS, ES6?) bearing in mind I may want to use this in Node and React.
- Can I obtain the same sort of dependency injection as I get with angular modules?
- Is any **$q** replacement framework (such as Bluebird?) OK or are there restrictions depending on the module format I go with?
- I'm clearly not the first person to do this (despite not finding any usable info) so if there are guides, or even conversion tools :-D that you could point to I'd be most grateful.

Comment: You can't 'convert' Angular to CJS/ES6 modules, because they are apples and oranges. As a rule of thumb, there should be core package and wrappers for target frameworks. If $q is replaced with another implementation (why not `Promise`?), this will require to additionally wrap promises with $q at some point to make digest-aware. Check https://github.com/ui-router and https://github.com/js-data for framework-agnostic implementations.